# Boolean PHP MySQL And OR Not Search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Can anybody help, i'm trying to build a search using php that searches a text field in mysql.

I would like users to be able to enter a must have criteria, an or criteria and a not criteria, as well as being able to search for strings, so for example:

("This phrase" OR "That phrase") AND word

At present i'm using the example below to generate a search string:

```
    $all = $row['and_search'] ;
    $any = $row['or_search'] ;
    $none = $row['not_search'];
    if((!$all) || ($all == "")) { $all = ""; } else { $all = "$all"; }
    if((!$any) || ($any == "")) { $any = ""; } 
    if((!$none) || ($none == "")) { $none = ""; } else { $none = "$none"; }
```

The above works brilliantly for only single words, but not searches such as the example above.

Any ideas how I can change achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, if I understood correctly, you should use javascript + mysql reflection (to get the fields from the sql table). Using javascript you can have an add/remove field which has the criteria you want. It's pretty much very complicated. You should also check for hacks like someone using a semicolon (;) and then type DROP DATABASE xxx or something

Answer (score 0):

Strip $all, $any and $none by whitespace into arrays. Than join them like

```
$newAll = '("' . join('" OR "', split(' ', $all)) . '")';
```